# Lines with easelJS using Ticker

Tags: html, drawing, html5-canvas, easeljs, ticker

I started learning html5 and easelJS two days ago, and I'm working on a game. Now I ran into some problems of course :)

I know I can draw a line with the code:

```
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(100, 150);
context.lineTo(450, 50);
context.stroke();
```

But as far as I know, you shouldn't mix context with easelJS's Ticker/Stage! I use Ticker to update the stage on certain FPS (update would erase the line in this case anyway right?).

Now what I want is to draw a line in tick method on certain occasions (key press) - BUT i need to draw a line slowly, so the user can see it moving towards the end. When a key gets pressed, some functions are called, and I could set some global variable according to which I would perform line drawing in the tick function …

I figured I could use moveTo/lineTo in a loop and increase coordinates accordingly.

What is the best way to approach this, am I missing something or maybe thinking about it totally wrong?

I checked [Drawing a Line in a html5 canvas using EaselJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996060/drawing-a-line-in-a-html5-canvas-using-easeljs) but he has static coordinates and he doesn't need to see the line moving as well.

I'm looking forward to any suggestions/corrections, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Drawing a line in easeljs

Check out this [rudimentary snake game](http://jsfiddle.net/fbAW9/1/) I made in jsfiddle. *Note: you'll need to click into the bottom right window to gain focus and use the arrow keys to control the snake.* With easeljs, you'll need to subscribe to the model of using DisplayObjects to construct your game environment. The **DisplayObject** is the building block for all UI content. In this case, I am using a **Shape** object which is a child class of DisplayObject, and is used to draw vector content. You'll also want to familiarize yourself with the [Graphics](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Graphics.html) class in easeljs. Each shape has a graphics property on which you will make all your drawing api calls.

```
var line = new createjs.Shape();
line.graphics.setStrokeStyle(3);
line.graphics.beginStroke(color);
line.graphics.moveTo(startX, startY);
startY++;
line.graphics.lineTo(startX, startY);
line.graphics.endStroke();
```

### Updating the stage in real time

In order to achieve the line movement, you will need listen to the "tick" event of **Ticker** object. In the jsfiddle example, I've added the both the stage as a listener, and a window scoped function where the line drawing will occur.

```
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);
```

You will also notice I've added a onkeydown listener to the window to set our key modifiers which control the direction of the snake.

```
window.onkeydown = function(e){
    color = createjs.Graphics.getRGB(0xFFFFFF * Math.random(), 1);
    switch(e.which){
        case 38:
            wPressed = false;
            ePressed = false;
            sPressed = false;
            nPressed = true;
            break;
        case 39:
            nPressed = false;
            sPressed = false;
            wPressed = false;
            ePressed = true;
            break;
        case 40:
            wPressed = false;
            ePressed = false;
            nPressed = false;
            sPressed = true;
            break;
        case 37:
            nPressed = false;
            sPressed = false;
            ePressed = false;
            wPressed = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Finally, in the tick function, you will make your drawing calls and update the x/y position based on the current direction. Remember the tick function gets called every frame, based on your current frames per second which is set using [this static function](http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Ticker.html#method_setFPS).

```
function tick(){
    if(nPressed)
    {
        line.graphics.setStrokeStyle(3);
        line.graphics.beginStroke(color);
        line.graphics.moveTo(startX, startY);
        startY--;
        line.graphics.lineTo(startX, startY);
        line.graphics.endStroke();
    }

    if(ePressed)
    {
        line.graphics.setStrokeStyle(3);
        line.graphics.beginStroke(color);
        line.graphics.moveTo(startX, startY);
        startX++;
        line.graphics.lineTo(startX, startY);
        line.graphics.endStroke();
    }

    if(wPressed)
    {
        line.graphics.setStrokeStyle(3);
        line.graphics.beginStroke(color);
        line.graphics.moveTo(startX, startY);
        startX--;
        line.graphics.lineTo(startX, startY);
        line.graphics.endStroke();
    }

    if(sPressed)
    {
        line.graphics.setStrokeStyle(3);
        line.graphics.beginStroke(color);
        line.graphics.moveTo(startX, startY);
        startY++;
        line.graphics.lineTo(startX, startY);
        line.graphics.endStroke();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, it works! I don't understand why a second ticker (for the stage) is needed though?

Comment: Adding the stage as a listener to the Ticker is the "built-in" way to call **stage.update();**, thus refreshing the stage. Alternatively you could manually add the stage.update() line to your own tick function.

Comment: whoops, i missed that you lack that line in your tick function - Yes, as you said, I have stage.update(event); in my tick function. Thanks again